# How to get normal src of an coded image like this in php?

Tags: php, src

Hi there I works with simple `php` parser to save imgs form external server...So I want to get an normal `src` of an picture
but it seem below `img` elements has an unusuall `src` ...

Is there anyway to turn this code to normal `src` or at least first save it in my server?

Note: text in `src` is too long...more than 170000 chars...I removed most of them to insert here to show you...

```
<img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
```

Comment: Read SRC -> Decode it to base 64 -> Now you have image -> save this file to folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy all of the src text after `base64,` and use php's `base64_decode` function to decode it. Once there you can write it to a jpg file if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("../images/folder16.gif"))
?>
```

You can use PHP function to get the image coded.
See this working example :

```
<?php 
  $img = base64_encode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png"));
echo "<img src='data:image/gif;base64,".$img."' />";

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow the following steps

```
<?php

// [1] Prepare your page HTML content
$html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,image_[1]_valid_base_64_encoded_string">';
$html .= '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,image_[2]_valid_base_64_encoded_string">';
$html .= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,image_[3]_valid_base_64_encoded_string">';
$html .= '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,image_[4]_valid_base_64_encoded_string">';

// [2] Get all src attributes
$xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html));
$src = $xpath->evaluate("//img/@src");

// [3] Loop src attributes and push image info to $images arary
$images = array();
foreach ($src as $attr)
{
    $data = explode('/', $attr->value);
    $data = str_replace(';', ',', $data[1]);

    list($extension, $type, $encoded_string) = explode(',', $data);

    // push to images array
    $images[] = array(
        'extension' => strtolower($extension),
        'image_base64' => $encoded_string,
    );
}

// results
echo '<pre>';
print_r($images);
echo '</pre>';

// [4] Move images to directory
// @file_put_contents("path/to/dir/image_name.$extension",  base64_decode($encoded_string));
```

// print_r($images) output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [extension] => png
            [image_base64] => image_[1]_valid_base_64_encoded_string
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [extension] => gif
            [image_base64] => image_[2]_valid_base_64_encoded_string
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [extension] => jpeg
            [image_base64] => image_[3]_valid_base_64_encoded_string
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [extension] => jpg
            [image_base64] => image_[4]_valid_base_64_encoded_string
        )

)
```